# Showing the correct version number of an extension in the about dialog in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsixmanifest

When developing extensions for Visual Studio you specify the version number of the extension in the `vsixmanifest` file like this:

```xml
<Metadata>
    <Identity ... Version="2.1.3" ... />
```

This will show the version number `2.1.3` in the extensions modal as expected. But the version number is not correctly shown on the extension name in the *About Microsoft Visual Studio* dialog. Example here:

[image: About Microsoft Visual Studio dialog]

This is just an example and doesn't relate to the `2.1.3` version number. But I see that an extension I have built also display `1.0` in the version number in this dialog even though I specified a higher version string in the `vsixmanifest` file.

Where can I modify the version number displayed in the *About Microsoft Visual Studio* dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version number (and other information) displayed in Help/About comes from the registration in your derived AsyncPackage class:

```
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "2.5", IconResourceID = 400)] // Info on this package for Help/About
```

Comment: Thanks!! And now that I know where to look, the comment even says that ‍♂️ "This attribute is used to register the information needed to show this package in the Help/About dialog of Visual Studio."